Exception has occurred: UnicodeDecodeError
I have a working Python script receiving messages from Azure Servicebus and saves them to a T-SQL table. The messages comes in a JSON string. However sometimes I'll get the error - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 172: invalid continuation byte. I have searched for solutions but not been able to find any. Can anyone help?
The Python script I'm using to receive the messages from the Azure Servicebus is from Microsoft - Azure Service Bus - Receive Messages. I have no control over the messages - just been giving an endpoint.
I'm running Python 3.12


I have a working Python script receiving messages from Azure Servicebus and saves them to a T-SQL table. The messages comes in a JSON string. However sometimes I'll get the error - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 172: invalid continuation byte.

This error occurs when the data is not encoded properly. To solve this error , you need to firstly get to know what is type encoding then replace the errors .
Below is the way I solve the error:
import chardet as rith

rith_data = b'{"text": "Hello Rithwik Bojja"}\xd8\x00'
try:
    test_decode = rith_data.decode('utf-8')
except UnicodeDecodeError as ri:
    print(f"The UnicodeDecodeError has occurred: {ri}")
data_decode_repl = rith_data.decode('utf-8', errors='replace')
print("Decoded the data by replacing:", data_decode_repl)
ri_out = rith.detect(rith_data)
tst_enc = ri_out ['encoding']
msg = rith_data.decode(tst_enc, errors='replace')
print(f"The type of encoding is: {tst_enc}")
print("The message without errors is :", msg)


So, before sending messages to T-Sql, use above steps, so that UnicodeDecodeError is solved.

Problem is solved. They cleared the queues in the Azure Service Bus and after that the problem was gone. They could not explain what the problem was.
